# Проблемы с Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

Из Intelij IDEA:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
>             Searched in the following locations:
>             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom
>             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.jar
>             Required by: project : Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Intelij IDEA - последняя версия. В Android Studio вообще нет возможности создать андроид проект, а доступ к SDK-Manager (в Android Studio) отсутствует после обновления (версия студии - 2.3.3).

Comment: Что значит отсутствует доступ к менеджеру в студии? Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager. И что значит нет возможности создать андроид проект? File -> New -> New Project.

Comment: В Tools нет ни пункта Android, ни SDK Manager (в Android Studio). В  Intelij IDEA с этим все в порядке, но возникаеют проблемы со сборкой (вышеуказанные проблемы).

Comment: Уверены, что это Android Studio а не IDEA? Переустановите.

Comment: Я устанавливал с офф. сайта студию для андроид разработки.

Comment: Не на линукс случайно ставите?

Comment: Нет. У меня Windows и скачивал я версию, которую автоматически подобрал сайт.

Comment: Удалите, перезагрузитесь, установите заново. Согласитесь, что нелогично, что ide, предназначенная для разработки под андроид не позволяет создать андроид проект, и поэтому нужно использовать другую ide. Видимо при установке что-то пошло не так.

Comment: Полностью согласен, но я уже перестанавливал несколько раз - результат один и тот же. Причем, началось все с неделю назад, когда мой AVG съел adb.exe и я не мог запускать приложения (решил переустановить студию - здесь та все и началось...).

Comment: Пробовали отключать антивирус при установке?

Comment: Да, в последний раз так и делал.

Comment: Ну так всё верно - плагин версии 3.3 не существует! Исправьте на 2.3.3 (last stable).

Comment: А у Вас Винда случаем не 32-битная? Сайт, если что, подсовывает версию для x64

Comment: Система x64. Попробовал изменить версию на 2.3.3 выдает следущюю ошибку: 
Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: C:\Users\RooT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: Установите api26 или измените targetSDK на другой установленный

Answer (score 0):

В итоге все решилось установкой "старой" версии Android Studio (2.3.1)...